# html5 canvas - Saving paths or clip areas to reuse

Tags: javascript, html, optimization, canvas

I'm currently implementing a 2d deformable terrain effect in a game I'm working on and its going alright but I can envision it becoming a performance hog very fast as I start to add more layers to the effect.

Now what I'm looking for is a way to possibly save a path, or clipping mask or similar instead of having to store each point of the path in the terrain that i need to draw through each frame. And as I add more layers I will have to iterate over the path more and more which could contain thousands of points.

Some very simple code to demonstrate what I'm currently doing

```
for (var i = 0; i < aMousePoints.length; i++)
{
    cRenderContext.save();
    cRenderContext.beginPath();
    var cMousePoint = aMousePoints[i];
    cRenderContext.arc(cMousePoint.x, cMousePoint.y, 30, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
    cRenderContext.clip();
    cRenderContext.drawImage(cImg, 0, 0);
    cRenderContext.closePath();
    cRenderContext.restore();
}
```

Basically I'm after an effecient way to draw my clipping mask for my image over and over each frame

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Notice how your clipping region stays exactly the same except for its x/y location. This is a big plus.

The clipping region is one of the things that is saved and restored with `context.save()` and `context.restore()` so it is possible to save it that way (in other words defining it only once). When you want to place it, you will use `ctx.translate()` instead of arc's x,y.

But it is probably more efficient to do it a second way:

1. Have an in-memory canvas (never added to the DOM or shown on the page) that is solely for containing the clipping region and is the size of the clipping region
2. Apply the clipping region to this in-memory canvas, and then draw the image onto this canvas.
3. Then use `drawImage` with the in-memory canvas onto your game context. In other words: `cRenderContext.drawImage(in-memory-canvas, x, y);` where x and y are the appropriate location.

So this way the clipping region always stays in the same place and is only ever drawn once. The image is moved on the clipping-canvas and then drawn to look correct, and then the in-memory canvas is drawn to your main canvas. It should be much faster that way, [as calls to `drawImage` are far faster than creating and drawing paths.](http://simonsarris.com/blog/427-increasing-performance-by-caching-paths-on-canvas)

As a separate performance consideration, don't call `save` and `restore` unless you have to. They do take time and they are unnecessary in your loop above.

If your code is open-source, let me know and I'll take a look at it performance-wise in general if you want.

Comment: The second way sounds like the way to go! So I'm guessing the transparency of the mask canvas will just work? If i draw a path in the mask canvas only that path will be drawn into the second canvas as long as thats all i have in it? Big  help thanks!

Comment: Yep. If you need help getting an example working let me know and I'll create one for you

Comment: I have had serious struggles with optimization. I'm in a situation where I have to clip either an image or a video.  It doesn't seem like I can create a Path2d() to save a clip path. I've tried what you suggested, of creating a separate canvas in memory to do the clipping, but _that_ doesn't seem to work. Could you tell me what I'm doing wrong? http://codepen.io/paceaux/pen/egLOeR

Answer (score 11):

Why not have one canvas for the foreground and one canvas for the background? Like the following demo

**[Foreground/Background Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/gtTNR/3/)** (I may of went a little overboard making the demo :? I love messing with JS/canvas.

But basically the foreground canvas is transparent besides the content, so it acts like a mask over the background canvas.

Answer (score 6):

It looks like it is now possible with a new [path2D](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Path2D) object.

The new Path2D API (available from Firefox 31+) lets you store paths, which simplifies your canvas drawing code and makes it run faster. The constructor provides three ways to create a Path2D object:

```
new Path2D();     // empty path object
new Path2D(path); // copy from another path
new Path2D(d);    // path from from SVG path data
```

The third version, which takes SVG path data to construct, is especially handy. You can now re-use your SVG paths to draw the same shapes directly on a canvas as well:

```
var p = new Path2D("M10 10 h 80 v 80 h -80 Z");
```

Information is taken from [Mozilla official site](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2015/01/canvas-2d-new-docs-path2d-hit-regions/).